# Custom findOrFail for the API routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I think this should be implemented by default since I'm working in `routes/api.php`.

I want to give a 404 error JSON response in case that we don't find any rows for the given `id` argument on `findOrFail()` method.

Something like:

```
return response()->json([
    'status' => 'ERROR',
    'error' => '404 not found'
], 404);
```

Instead of the default `Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.` blade page.

I don't want to do:

```
$item = Model::find($id);
if (is_null($item)) {
    return response()->json([
        'status' => 'ERROR',
        'error' => '404 not found'
    ], 404);
}
```

Everywhere when I getting an `id`, and I wouldn't like to implement this in a middleware since it will cause some 'mess' on the api.php file.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can always catch the exception in the App\Exceptions\Handler.php

Import the exception into the class using the following:

```
use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
```

and in the render method, add

```
if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {

            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Record not found',
            ], 404);

        }
```

Answer (score 6):

Or use this, looks cleaner to me:

```php
try {
    $resource = Model::findorfail($id);
} catch (\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $e) {
    return response([
        'status' => 'ERROR',
        'error' => '404 not found'
    ], 404);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just to add, I ended up checking for these three exceptions:

1. Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
2. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException;
3. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

And then returning JSON if expected:

```
if ($request->expectsJson()) {
    return response()->json(['error' => $msg], $code);    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;

public function render($request, Throwable $e)
    {
        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
                return response()->json([
                    'message' => 'Record not found.',
                ], 404);
            }
        }

        return parent::render($request, $e);
    }
```